# Alternative ssh server and client without valid IP. Linux/ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop

Is there a way to setup an alternative ssh server that does not need a valid IP address? For example, TeamViewer as server gives an id that you can use to connect. How can we achieve something similar for ssh in Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: you should try to do in the good way, do port fordwarding, and if you have dynamic ip, use ddns. and if you want an alternative of TeamViewer for linux you could try Team Viewer for linux

Comment: I don't have any control over the public servers.

Comment: anyway this question is off-topic http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @FranciscoTapia Why exactly do you tink this is off-topic? The question is not asking for software - it;s asking how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Teamviewer act as relay, the machines running TeamViewer announce to a server registering his Ip Address and providing an ID so when your host want to connect to a Remote machines you can use that ID and TV Server will relay your conection to the correct Remote Machine.

```
                                 / [Remote Machine]
                                /
                               /
[Your Host]  ----> [TV Servers]
                               \
                                \
                                 \ [Remote Machine]
```

**The positive**, there is a [Linux Version of Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) but it doesnt work as [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) it could be compared with [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).... protocols.

**My suggestion**, you could set an SSH server and set-up [Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) that will make your host visible from the [WAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network).

if you have Dynamic IP Adress you can also use an [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) and it will update your ip when changes making possible to connect with a permanent Name Server.

Aditional Information

> How do I install TeamViewer on my Ubuntu system?
>
> To install TeamViewer on your Ubuntu system, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Download the TeamViewer full version [Here](http://www.teamviewer.com/download).
> 2. Open the `teamviewer_linux.deb` file with a double click. The TeamViewer installation package will open in the Ubuntu Software
>      Center.
> 3. Click on the Install button. The Authenticate dialog box will open.
> 4. Enter the administrative password.
> 5. Click on the Authenticate button. TeamViewer will be installed.
>           The status within the Ubuntu Software Center changes to Installed. TeamViewer is installed on your Ubuntu system.

[Source](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/427-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Ubuntu-system)